# Invalid SQL Syntax CLI0118E

Tags: sql, db2, driver

I am trying to execute the below query and getting Invalid SQL Syntax error
.   [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0118E  Invalid SQL syntax. SQLSTATE=37000(37000,-99999). Is it anything to do with driver upgrade? It was working fine a while ago. Please advice. Thanks in advance.

```
    select a.name_task as nameTask, a.cd_sts as cdSts, a.desc_err_msg as   
               statusDesc
             from task_log a,(
                select id_bus_procss, name_task , id_run,  
            max(dt_lst_updt) as dt_lst_updt  from task_log
                 where id_run = '1'
                 and id_bus_procss = '14'
                 and name_task in ({0})
                 and dt_lst_updt >= (
        select dt_evnt_sts from 
                            sf_evntflow_sts 
                         where id_run = '1' and   
                  id_evntflow ='15' 

                     and  cd_evnt_sts in (''CLN'',''RTY'' ) 
                         )
                 group by id_bus_procss, name_task, id_run) 
                 X
            where a.dt_lst_updt = X.dt_lst_updt
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are executing this on stored procedure , Try this may help, Remove the new line character and separate the parameters by
**spaces** .
Or otherwise try upgrade.......

Comment: This is a query that gets called from the application, not as stored procedure. Can you please explain this ,Remove the new line character and separate the parameters by spaces

Comment: Close your query editor  and then reopen your editor then try to execute.

Comment: I shutdown my rapid sql and reopened and executed in a new query editor but still the same error.

Comment: it happens some times when you done operation with antivirus in your system, try to update your driver .

Answer (score 0):

if you try this query its better?

```
select a.name_task as nameTask, a.cd_sts as cdSts, a.desc_err_msg as statusDesc
from task_log a,
( select b.id_bus_procss, b.name_task , b.id_run, max(b.dt_lst_updt) as dt_lst_updt 
  from task_log b inner join sf_evntflow_sts c on b.id_run=c.id_run and c.id_evntflow ='15' 
  and c.cd_evnt_sts in (''CLN'',''RTY'' ) and b.dt_lst_updt >=c.dt_evnt_sts
  where b.id_run = '1' and b.id_bus_procss = '14' and b.name_task in ({0})
  group by b.id_bus_procss, b.name_task, b.id_run
) as X
where a.dt_lst_updt = X.dt_lst_updt
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong in the above query? It was working fine until a few days back.

Comment: your subselect and dt_lst_updt >= (subselect) must return one row and i think its not case now.